# Internationalization in JSF 2.0

Tags: internationalization, jsf-2

I'm wondering how internationalization works in jsf? I have read tutorial on [coreservlets.com](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Event-Handling.pdf) about it, but in my case it works slightly differently. In that tutorial  said that i have to use

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(newLocale);
```

in actionListener(listener for changing locale) and also backing bean has to have property `getCurrentLocale()` to use it in `<f:view>` tag.

I have 2 property files with messages(default and with specified locale), they are registered in `faces-config.xml`. `<f:view>` tag I have only at one page(index.xhtml)

```
<f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">
...
</f:view>
```

Also I have 2 buttons(with actionListener) for each locale. In backing bean I simply modify current locale variable(don't use `getViewRoot().setLocale(newLocale)`). But locale changes for all pages(even if they don't have `<f:view locale="#{bean.locale}">`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lets say you have following two messages files

```
    messages.properties
    messages_de.properties
```

**Setting the Application Locale**

There are three ways of setting the Application Locale and I think **you need the first one** here.

**1-You can let the browser choose the locale.**

Set the default and supported locales in `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml:`

```
<faces-config>
   <application>
      <locale-config>
         <default-locale>en</default-locale>
         <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
      </locale-config>
  </application>
</faces-config>
```

When a browser connects to your application, it usually includes an Accept-Language value in the HTTP header

**2-You can set the locale programatically.**

Call the setLocale method of the UIViewRoot object:

```
UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
viewRoot.setLocale(new Locale("de"));
```

**3-You can set the locale for an individual page** 

By using the `f:view` element with a locale attribute—for example:

```
<f:view locale="de">
```

The locale can be dynamically set:

```
<f:view locale="#{user.locale}"/>
```

**Declaring message bundles**
Now that the Locale is set you can use one of the following two ways to declare message bundles

**1-Via faces-config**
The simplest way is to supply a file named faces-config.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your application, with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0">
   <application>
      <resource-bundle>
         <base-name>com.corejsf.messages</base-name>
         <var>msgs</var>
      </resource-bundle>
   </application>
</faces-config>
```

**2-At each JSF page that needs access it.**
Instead of using a global resource bundle declaration, you can add the f:loadBundle element to each JSF page that needs access to the bundle, like this:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.corejsf.messages" var="msgs"/>
```

In either case, the messages in the bundle are accessible through a map variable with the name msgs.

**Showing appropriate label on button**
Now lets say default properties file i.e english has property

```
next=Next
```

and German has equivallent i.e

```
next=Weiter
```

And you have set the locale and declared mesg bundle you can access it to put the label on a command button like

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs.next}"/>
```

*Above Answer is extracted and modified from **[Hortsmen Core Java Server Faces book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012896)**.*

Comment: I would like to add something: In the 3. and 2. point. Instead of doing it for each JSF page, you can doing in a template.xhtml.